# Selecting Adjacent Sibling without intervening text nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Due to a sad situation I receive HTML like this:

```html
<p>Perform the following commands:
   <code>&gt; cd /foo</code><code>&gt; adb shell</code><code># ps</code>
</p>
```

and I need to make code like appear visually like:

```
Perform the following commands:
> cd /foo
> adb shell
# ps
```

I thought I'd be tricky and use the [CSS Adjacent Sibling Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors):

```css
code + code:before { content:'\A'; white-space:pre }
```

...but then I discovered that this applies even to something like:

```html
<p>If you go to your <code>C:\</code> directory and run <code>dir</code> …</p>
```

Is there a CSS-only solution to select adjacent elements **without intervening non-element nodes**?

*If and only if there is not, feel free to suggest a JavaScript (including jQuery) solution.*

Comment: Can you give us a fiddle to work with? and put a div with the output you want to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
$('code').each(function() {
    var prev = this.previousSibling;
    var next = this.nextSibling;
    if ((prev && prev.tagName === 'CODE') ||
        (next && next.tagName === 'CODE')) {
        $(this).addClass('block');
    }
});​
```

Then in your CSS use the `.block` selector to add `display: block` and any other desired styles to the matched elements.

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/JYzGg/

It would be pretty easy to code this as pure Javascript if you don't already have jQuery loaded - jQuery just happens to make adding the class easier than pure JS if you should have other class names already on those elements.

Comment: @Alnitak Well, at least you get the +15 ;) Thanks.

Comment: Regarding adding the class in pure JS: is there something wrong with `foo.className += " bar";`?

Comment: @Phrogz depends on whether the browser normalises the string to eliminate duplicates - my code above will actually update any "middle" elements twice.

Comment: @Phrogz note also that your formulation is slightly incorrect - the style does need to be applied to _both_ `<code>` elements that are in a pair.  Doing what you tried to do with your `code + code:before` would never have worked because it wouldn't have made the _first_ `<code>` element drop onto a line of its own.

Answer (score 1):

While I see that you've already accepted an answer, I thought I'd offer this as an alternative:

```
$('code').each(
    function(){
        if (this.previousSibling == this.previousElementSibling){
            $(this).addClass('block');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('inline');
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pWMeF/1/).

This will, of course, only run on those browsers that implement `previousElementSibling` (but I think the majority of browsers that implement the CSS pseudo-elements do implement this feature).

And, in pure vanilla JavaScript:

```
var codes = document.getElementsByTagName('code');

for (var i=0, len=codes.length; i<len; i++){
    var cur = codes[i];
    codes[i].className = cur.previousSibling == cur.previousElementSibling ? 'block' : 'inline';
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pWMeF/2/).

And because I prefer a slightly tidier approach to adding classes (as opposed to explicitly adding a space-character before the new class I'm adding) there's this approach as well:

```
function addClass(elem,newClass){
    if (!elem) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var curClass = elem.className;
        if (curClass.length){
            return curClass + ' ' + newClass;
        }
        else {
            return newClass;
        }
    }
}

var codes = document.getElementsByTagName('code');

for (var i=0, len=codes.length; i<len; i++){
    var cur = codes[i];
    codes[i].className = cur.previousSibling == cur.previousElementSibling ? addClass(cur,'block') : addClass(cur,'inline');
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pWMeF/3/).

---

**Edited** in response to the comments raised by Alnitak (the second of which I'd realised as I went to make myself a cup of tea, the first I hadn't considered at all):

```
var codes = document.getElementsByTagName('code');

for (var i=0, len=codes.length; i<len; i++){
    var cur = codes[i];
    codes[i].className = cur.previousSibling == codes[i-1] || cur.nextSibling == codes[i+1]? addClass(cur,'block') : addClass(cur,'inline');
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pWMeF/6/)

References:

- [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.nextElementSibling).
- [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.previousElementSibling).

Comment: while your code checks that the previous node is actually an element, it _doesn't_ check that it's a `<code>` element.

Comment: by only checking the previous node it also fails to modify the _first_ `<code>` element that appears in a sequence.

Comment: @Alnitak: I hadn't considered the first of your points until I read your comment, though I was about to address the latter (after making a cup of tea, admittedly)...still, I think it's addressed now.

Comment: Your fix is still wrong - the `i == 0` check only matches the very first `<code>` element in the _document_, not the first in any _sequence_ that might appear.

Comment: Edited while you were commenting, the `i == 0` felt too much like a kludge. Even for me. Though now, and I hadn't looked at your answer (since first deciding to answer the question), I feel like I just plagiarised. Darn...

Comment: Yeah, that looks better.  Fortunately the two "array index out-of-bounds errors" aren't actually errors in JS ;-)

Comment: and don't worry about plagiarism - your pure JS solution is actually kinda neat in the way it accesses the live nodelist to check the sibling relationships.  It avoids the extra condition in the `node && node.prop` tests that I have in my jQuery answer.