# Style span element following another span without text content in between

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'd like to create CSS rule to style `span` elements which immediately follow some other span and there is no text content between them. So I want to style `<span class="bar">Second</span>` in this example:

```
<span class="parent">
  <span class="foo">First</span>
  <span class="bar">Second</span> <!-- this one! -->
</span>
<span class="parent">
  <span class="foo">Third</span>
  Some text.
  <span class="bar">Fourth</span> <!-- but not this! -->
</span>
```

I've tried using both `+` ([adjacent](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)) and `~` ([general](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)) combinators without success:

```
/* colours both "Second" and "Fourth" */
span.foo+span.bar {
  color: red;
}
```

Also I've tried some pseudoclasses:

```
/* colours "Third", "Some text." and "Fourth" */
span.parent :only-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

I'm looking for some working solution in pure CSS. It might use experimental features (like `:has`) but they must be supported by Chrome browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible using only CSS

Comment: Look the similar question with the answer using jquery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198007/selecting-adjacent-sibling-without-intervening-text-nodes

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai, thanks, this is a similar question. But it was asked 5 years ago, maybe something has changed since then?

Comment: Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the opening `<span>` immediately follows the preceding closing `</span>` like this:

```
<span>...</span><span>...</span>
```

there will *always* be a `textnode` between spans - even when there is no readable text, there will still be whitespace.

Consequently, you need to check for two conditions:

- is the **element** which precedes the `<span>`... a `<span>`?
- is the `textnode` which *immediately* precedes the `<span>`... just whitespace (or absent)?

If both these conditions are `true`, then you can dynamically add a class to the `<span>` under examination.

**Working Example:**

```js
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName('parent');

for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
    var spans = parents[i].getElementsByTagName('span');
    
    for (var j = 1; j < spans.length; j++) {

        // Checks preceding textNode for readable text
        var followsWhitespace = (/^\s*$/).test(spans[j].previousSibling.textContent);

        // Just in case there is no preceding textNode at all
        if (spans[j].previousSibling.nodeName === 'SPAN') {
            followsWhitespace = true;
        }

        // Identifies preceding element
        var previousElementName = spans[j].previousElementSibling.nodeName;

        if ((previousElementName === 'SPAN') && (followsWhitespace === true)) {
            spans[j].classList.add('follows-span');
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.follows-span {
font-weight: bold;
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<span class="parent">
  <span class="foo">First</span>
  <span class="bar">Second</span> <!-- this one! -->
</span>
<span class="parent">
  <span class="foo">Third</span>
  Some text.
  <span class="bar">Fourth</span> <!-- but not this! -->
</span>
```